# How do I echo an empty JSON curly brackets as a default value?

Tags: bash, variable

I can't seem to get an empty JSON `{}` to echo if an envvar is missing. I either have a trailing `}` in the output if set, or the escape displays.

```
bash-3.2$ unset X
bash-3.2$ echo "${X:-{}}"
{}
bash-3.2$ X=y
bash-3.2$ echo "${X:-{}}"
y}
bash-3.2$ echo "${X:-{\}}"
y
bash-3.2$ unset X
bash-3.2$ echo "${X:-{\}}"
{\}
bash-3.2$ echo "${X:-'{}'}"
'{}'
bash-3.2$ X=z
bash-3.2$ echo "${X:-'{}'}"
z
```

How do I escape it correctly?

Comment: Interesting, but with bash 4.3 `echo "${X:-{\}}"` worked just fine.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy That was fixed in 4.2; I recall some discussion about quoting of word expansions following parameter expansion operators to conform with the POSIX standard.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Quote your braces:

```
bash-3.2$ echo "${X:-"{}"}"
{}
bash-3.2$ X=y
bash-3.2$ echo "${X:-"{}"}"
y
bash-3.2$ unset X
bash-3.2$ echo "${X:-"{}"}"
{}
```

Inner *double* quotes are required here, which looks funny but is syntactically fine.

Single quotes won't work, and I'm not entirely sure why not. This is real nested quoting, not end-and-resume, which you can verify by putting spaces in. Double will work fine though.

Comment: I think this is the relevant sentence from the POSIX spec: "The '}' character that delimits the following parameter expansion modifications shall be determined as described previously in this section and in Double-Quotes." I interpret this as meaning the `word` following `:-` must be specifically double-quoted, so `"${X:-'{}'}"` is literally `${X:-'{}` followed by `'}`. Why the spec is so specific is unclear to me.

Comment: (The sentence referred to by "described previously" is "The matching closing brace shall be determined by counting brace levels, skipping over enclosed quoted strings, and command substitutions.")

Answer (score 10):

You can cheat and set a variable to be the empty result, and avoid the quoting issues

```
$ def="{}"
$ echo ${X:-$def}
{}
$ X=y
$ echo ${X:-$def}
y
$ unset X
$ echo ${X:-$def}
{}
$
```

Answer (score 5):

What I frequently do is make use of hex values for characters via `printf`:

```
bash-4.3$ echo "${X:-$(printf '\x7B\x7D')}"
{}
bash-4.3$ X="something"
bash-4.3$ echo "${X:-$(printf '\x7B\x7D')}"
something
```

Slightly verbose, but works  without too much stressing out about quotes.